# Where is the render display mode setting in 2.8x?

Tags: rendering, interface

I can't find display mode in 2.8x versions. In older versions when you hit the render button from the navigation there was a display mode option. Now it's gone.

Where can I find it?

Comment: OK, so you want to change how the render is displayed, right? You should state it more clearly. It's not a 'button' you are talking about, that's a menu and that is not 'navigation', it's the topbar. It's best to post a screenshot if you are not sure about the terminology. You can find how parts of the UI are called in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) This is important, because other way, it's impossible to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: people who are new to blender/3d modelling/python sometimes don't even know how to ask the question they have, I'm definitely one of them ..  could have used more detail or a screenshot, but seems you knew exactly what he meant

Answer (score 2):

You can access the settings related to displaying the render in the Preferences now *(Interface > Editors > Temporary Windows > Render In)*:

[image]

To get to the Preferences you can hit <kbd>F4</kbd> followed by <kbd>P</kbd> or go to *Edit menu* on the Topbar and choose Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Martynas Žiemys that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!